# ProgressBar Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two methods which are savePreferences

```
private void savePreferences(String key, double value) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, String.valueOf(value));
    editor.commit();
}
```

and I saved value in it (its necessary BCS currentProgress is in another block of code)

```
savePreferences("currentProgress", currentProgress);
```

and getPreferences

```
public String getPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue",0);
    preferences.getString(key, "");
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}
```

and I want to set the progress bar progress using

```
progress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(getPreferences("currentProgress")));
```

but it keeps crushing my app, what should I do to save progress bar progress for the next time the user runs the app?

Comment: setProgress is in onCreate method bcs I want to show progress everytime user runs an app

Comment: Maybe give the error message? Otherwise there is no possible way anyone could help you

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sh, PID: 7929 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sh/com.example.sh.MySecoundActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.0"

Comment: Hi @duszyn_ please use int data type for storing progress. editor.putInt(key, progress); like this and preferences.getInt(key, 0); for getting value from preferences. Because progress bar returns and accepts progress value in int. Adding unnecessary data type conversion is not needed

Comment: @duszyn_ the compiler shows that you gave currentProgress the value of "100.0", this is a floating point integer, you need to use a normal integer if you want to use Integer.parseInt() on it